# converting unix time to string time with date command

Tags: date

I have read the man pages for date command, but there is no option for converting unix time to string time. I found some websites telling this:

```
date -d @1343715322
```

there is no option like `@` in the man and info pages. Can someone explain it?

Comment: What kind of `date` implementation you have? `@` is specific for GNU `date`.

Comment: My manpage for GNU date also doesn't describe `@` but still uses it in an example. Yet I don't understand your question. `@` seems to be the only way to do this with `date` so where's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the GNU date manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Seconds-since-the-Epoch. The same explanation is in the coreutils info pages.

> If you precede a number with ‘@’, it represents an internal time stamp
>   as a count of seconds. The number can contain an internal decimal
>   point (either ‘.’ or ‘,’); any excess precision not supported by the
>   internal representation is truncated toward minus infinity. Such a
>   number cannot be combined with any other date item, as it specifies a
>   complete time stamp.
>
> Internally, computer times are represented as a count of seconds since
>   an epoch—a well-defined point of time. On GNU and POSIX systems, the
>   epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 utc, so ‘@0’ represents this time, ‘@1’
>   represents 1970-01-01 00:00:01 utc, and so forth. GNU and most other
>   POSIX-compliant systems support such times as an extension to POSIX,
>   using negative counts, so that ‘@-1’ represents 1969-12-31 23:59:59
>   utc.
>
> Traditional Unix systems count seconds with 32-bit two's-complement
>   integers and can represent times from 1901-12-13 20:45:52 through
>   2038-01-19 03:14:07 utc. More modern systems use 64-bit counts of
>   seconds with nanosecond subcounts, and can represent all the times in
>   the known lifetime of the universe to a resolution of 1 nanosecond.
>
> On most hosts, these counts ignore the presence of leap seconds. For
>   example, on most hosts ‘@915148799’ represents 1998-12-31 23:59:59
>   utc, ‘@915148800’ represents 1999-01-01 00:00:00 utc, and there is no
>   way to represent the intervening leap second 1998-12-31 23:59:60 utc.

Answer (score 4):

You usually won't find details like this in the man pages.

Check the `info date`, you will find this in the "Date input formats" section.